# Extract the custom action requested by user as an entity with rasa NLU

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have a use case where i want to create a chat bot to log user requests in our request tracking tool.
I'm having difficult in extracting is the action requested by user, as it need not follow any pattern.

Examle user requests may be

- create case **restart service srv1**
- can you please create a case to **restart the service srv1**
- can you create a case to **resend report1** and assign it to @username
- **unable to login to application.** please create a case

In above cases, i want to create an entity with following values
**restart the service srv1**, **resend report1**, **unable to login to application** etc.

Can you suggest the best way to extract the user request. As of now, i'm capturing the whole request which is not very elegant.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Comment: Hello David. I have given the example user inputs and the expected entity value as output. I'm new to NLU. I went through all the tutorials posted in https://blog.rasa.com and https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/entity-extraction/ but i'm unable to find a similar use case. Most example tries to find some specific key from the user input or understand the intent but do not have a case where we need to extract the request user is making. I'm continuing to explore and if you have any pointers, that would also be very helpful.